# Last layer, rotate 3 edges

Tags: rubiks-cube, twisty-puzzles

Up until a few months ago I was happily solving my 4x4x4 cube, then, thanks to a medical thing, I've lost/forgotten a few algorithms. I've got all of them back except 1, rotating the last 3 edges.

**edit: this isn't a parity issue, it's the same as the 3x3x3 case** (sorry I wasn't clear)

What I remember is this:

1. Everything is oriented correctly and the corners are positioned correctly.
2. The cube is oriented so the correctly positioned edge is facing front and the last layer is on top.
3. I never rotate the back face.

I've found a quite a few algorithms that can solve it, but not for those criteria. I've not found one that has the correct edge facing front, and when I rotate the algorithm I'll need to rotate the back face.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you perhaps have a picture? If I understand correctly, everything is correct, except for three top-layer edges that need to rotate around (either in a clockwise or counterclockwise rotation)? In which case it's just [a regular 3x3x3 case](https://i.postimg.cc/VNP9s11Y/a.png), instead of a 4x4x4 parity case.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Yes it's just the same as the 3x3x3 case, it's not parity. I've updated the question. If you post your comment as an answer with the notation, I'll mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OP confirmed it was a regular 3x3x3 case, where three of the edges have to rotate around without orienting them. In that case, the following algorithm could be used with the solved fourth edge at the top-front:

> [image]
>  R' U' R U' R' U2 R U R U R' U R U2 R' U'
>
>  These are the PLL Ua and Ub perms (depending on whether you have to rotate them around clockwise or counterclockwise), so you can find a lot of alternative algorithms accomplishing the same result [here](https://www.speedsolving.com/wiki/index.php/PLL#U_Permutation_:_a).

Comment: Thanks again. That's exactly what I was looking for :)

Comment: Also, thanks for the link to speed solving, I'm going to go with this one.